# css page continues to work even after deleting and saving

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello Im new to web development. I have created a simple php page. I linked a css file to the page but it is acting odd. Even when i remove certain things such as the background image and save the css file it keeps the background image. I've even tried deleting the entire CSS file and it still keeps everything somehow. Worst part is it wont let me update the css file. It just keeps the things ive had before. "global.css" is the only css file in its path. along with 2 php files. I am using xammp apache server to host it locally.

I am truly bewildered.

https://postimg.cc/gallery/2VH2m4v - Photos for reference.

EDIT: IT HAS BEEN SOLVED. THE CSS WAS BEING CACHED CTRL + F5 WORKED FOR ME.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="icon" href="globallogo.png">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">

    <div class="pagetitle">
<h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<title> Home </title>



<html lang="en">

    <div class="glogo">
<img src="globallogo.png" alt="sum" height="150px" width="150px">
</div>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="linklist">

<li>
<a href="art.php">Art</a>


<li>
</div>

<script>
   

    </script>





</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `Ctrl`+`F5` to reload the page without cache.

Comment: It may be getting cached.

Comment: Update! Sebastion Solved it. It was being cached. Thank you!